# How to flatten Nuget package contentFiles?

Tags: package, nuget, flatten, nuspec, buildaction

Nuget package issues - buildAction, copyToOutput, flatten are ignored

Package project (ThisProject.vbproj)- .Net Standard Library 2.0, .nuspec file:

```
<references>
      <reference file="ThisProject.dll"></reference>
      <reference file="First.dll"></reference>
      <reference file="Second.dll"></reference>
      <reference file="...."></reference>
    </references>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/*" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="contentFiles\any\any\First.dll" target="lib\any\any\First.dll"></file>
    <file src="contentFiles\any\any\Second.dll" target="lib\any\any\Second.dll"></file>
   <file src="contentFiles\any\any\....dll" target="lib\any\any\.....dll"></file>
    </files>
```

When importing in .net ClickOnce Framework 4.6.1 Project, the contentFiles are still in the subfolders (flatten is ignored), Build Action and CopyToOutputDirectory are the defaults (buildAction,copyToOutput  are ignored)

Read all the documentation I could find e.g.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some misunderstanding about this part.

**First**, **contentFiles** works for new-sdk projects(`Net Core` and `Net Standard`) with [PackageReference nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) rather than `Net Framework` project with [packages.config nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config).

And `contentFiles` works for content files rather than lib folder. So you should not pack these dll files on `target="lib\any\any\.....dll"`. You should pack them into `contentFiles` folder.

Use this:

```
<contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/*" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
 </contentFiles>

<files>
    <file src="xxx\First.dll(the physical, relative path of the dll on your project folder)" target="contentFiles\any\any\First.dll"></file>
   <file src="xxx\Second.dll(the physical, relative path of the dll on your project folder)" target="contentFiles\any\any\Second.dll"></file>
   <file src="xxx\....dll(the physical, relative path of the dll on your project folder)" target="contntFiles\any\any\.....dll"></file>

<files>
```

Then, you should install this nuget package on a **Net Core** project.

When you finish it, repack the project with `nuget pack` command, then, before you install the new one, [clean the nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) to remove the old previous version. Then, install the new version on a **Net Core** project and you can see the effect like this:

[image]

======================================================================

If you still want to have this function on a `Net Framework` project, you should pack these files on `content` node rather than `contentFiles`.

And you only need to add two lines:

```
        <contentFiles>
              <files include="any/any/*" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
         </contentFiles>
        
        <files>
            <file src="xxx\First.dll(the physical, relative path of the dll on your project folder)" target="contentFiles\any\any\First.dll"></file>
           <file src="xxx\Second.dll(the physical, relative path of the dll on your project folder)" target="contentFiles\any\any\Second.dll"></file>
           <file src="xxx\....dll(the physical, relative path of the dll on your project folder)" target="contntFiles\any\any\.....dll"></file>
           
          <file src="xxx\First.dll(the physical, relative path of the dll on your project folder)" target="content"></file>
           <file src="xxx\Second.dll(the physical, relative path of the dll on your project folder)" target="content"></file>
    
   ..........

        <files>
```

**But** these simply cannot change the attributes of the imported file. And for net framework project, changing the property of the files cannot be done on `xxx.nuspec` file.

**You** should use [<packages_id>.props or targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) file.

**1)** create a file called `<packages_id>.props` under the build folder on the **Solution Explorer**, if your nuget package is named as `ThisProject.1.0.0.nupkg`, you should name it as `ThisProject.props` so that it will work.

This is mine:

[image]

**2)** add these on the props file:

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="First.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="Second.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        ......
            
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**3)** add a line on `nuspec` file to include the props file into the nupkg.

```
 <file src="build\xxx.props(the physical, relative path of the file on your project folder)" target="build"></file>
```

**4)** then repack the nuget package, clean the nuget caches, then install this new one on the Net Framework project with `packages.config`.

**Note**: although the **Properties** window of the imported content file on the solution explorer does not show the changed value and still shows the old one, the files are already copied into the output folder of the project. And it is an UI display issue on **Solution Explorer** and the changed values are already be used and work well. So you do not have to care much about that.