# Options for local hosted client side package management in VS2019?

Tags: npm, nuget, visual-studio-2019, yarnpkg, libman

A common issue I keep bumping into for web projects in net core, is the need for sharing javascript in easy to use modules from project to project. Often times large quantities of code written in VS project A could be very much used in project B, sometimes in the same solution.

Restrictions:

1. **Must be self hosted, not publicly exposed**, only within local network etc etc can access the libs/modules/packages/etc
2. Ideally can be performed via **visual studio projects** and make use of build tasks, powershell, msbuild, or other such automation tools to deploy and package, minify, bundle, etc etc the javascript libraries.
3. The absolute ideal is if this can all be **hosted from just a network folder**

## NPM/Yarn

I'm not super familiar with either of these, but is there a way we can drag and drop javascript code we've built into some designated folder, perhaps modify some form of manifest, json or xml file or what have you, and then anyone can just `npm install` those packages? I guess what I'm wondering is, is there a way to tell npm "This folder now is a source of packages you can install from"?

- Bonus points: If said "trust this folder" config can be set inside of the VS project, so if someone new grabs the git repo, it will just work "out of the box" and they dont need to go through steps configuring npm or yarn so it knows how to find those packages.

## Libman

Same as above, but mostly I'm trying to figure out if there is any way at all to configure libman from VS. It's the default and what is currently in use, but it just has its four default CDNs it comes with that it trusts and I am not seeing any way at all to tell Libman "Here's a now resource for files to trust, add that to the selectable drop down"

But I am seeing basically zero configuration as an option for libman, which is quite disappointing.

## Nuget

This is the other option that is already popular locally, but something about using nuget to deliver js files when NPM, Yarn, and Libman already exist sets my teeth on edge, but, we have I believe a locally hosted nuget server that could be used already, so the infrastructure I believe is already setup, if not, I know how to do it. I do like the fact that nuget 100% for sure could leverage actual projects and build steps and msbuild and etc for deploying.

## Conclusion

What's the popular and easy way to do this nowadays? Best case scenario is if there's a way to go, "Put a manifest.json file in the folder root that points to all the modules inside, then add it as a trusted source to your package manager, and now you can install those packages"

Comment: For nuget, you should [create such nuget package with content or contentFiles node for the shared javascripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722874/how-to-flatten-nuget-package-contentfiles/64748780#64748780),  and then create [a local shared nuget package source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65294087/is-there-a-better-way-of-downloading-nuget-packages-required-for-net-work-for-a/65301147#65301147) with the nuget package so that every staff can access it.  After that, every staff install that nuget packages, and can get the common shared javascript files.